# How do I get my husky mix puppy to want to train?

Tags: dogs, training

Background:

My husband and I just got two tamaskan puppies from two different litters two days apart from the same male. My female (Lyra) is fluffy and I think she has more husky in her, my husband's male (Squall) is short-haired and looks more like a German Shepherd. They are 12 weeks old now.

Squall loves to do tricks. Every time I get the treats out he follows me around looking me in the eyes, then does all the tricks we already learned (like sit, down, shake (paw), stay) and I've been teaching him "play dead", which he almost gets, but usually just rolls on his back and starts flailing his feet in the air +) so cute +) and "heel". He will literally do tricks as long as I keep trying to teach him.

Lyra on the other hand is so stubborn. She doesn't care about toys or treats or anything. I'm not even sure if she actually knows "sit", or if she just like sitting and does it whenever possible. I tried teaching her "down" by luring her with the treat to the ground, and she would just plaster on the floor with her face on it all spread out, not even looking at me. I'm not sure if that's her way or doing "down", but she will only do that with a treat MAYBE 5-6 times, never when I just say the command, and then she just stops and goes away.

I train them separately because Squall will completely take over and try to steal all the food, plus they distract each other. So I put them in their crates one at a time, but the crated puppy starts freaking out. Though they calm down after 5 minutes or so. Squall is usually much more opposed to being crated then Lyra, she just doesn't seem to care about anything ever.

She just seems super passive and like she just wants to lie down and not move all day. I think part of it might be because we're in Florida and it's 80 degrees in the house and she has that crazy thick coat, but still... I can't take them outside because it's high 90s right now, and I can't really play with them together because Squall is so much more into everything, Lyra just gives up and goes to do her own thing. Or they start play fighting. I think they prefer that to playing to me, at least Lyra does.

I've heard that training a husky is crazy hard, but I didn't think she'd have THAT much husky in her. Squall is much more like the GSD I used to have, much more fun.

**How can I get Lyra to be more interested in learning stuff?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teach them separately and when hungry.
Ideal training times are before breakfast and before supper, no snacks in between.
End on a high note, after last trick give her full breakfast/supper and give lots of loving.

Comment: I thought about that. So far they've had food available to them whenever they wanted it. I guess I can start putting their bowls away. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yep! I would also recommend portioning their food to prevent obesity. Many health issues arrise with overweight pets and by portioning you also save money, it's a win/win :)